# Blazor: How to show a loading text immediately after clicking a button?

Tags: asp.net, razor, async-await, blazor

I have a blazor page that is used to create a user, when the button is clicked, i want to display a loading text. and when it is done, i want to hide the text, here is my code:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @if (@IsLoading) {
            <div>Loading</div>
        } else {
        <div class="add-user">
            <PageHeader Text="Add User" />

            <form Model="NewUser" class="user-form">
                <div class="line">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" @bind="NewUser.Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" @bind="NewUser.Email" />
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <div>
                        <label>Gender</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="male">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male" @onchange="UpdateGender" checked="@IsMaleRadioButtonChecked" />
                        <label for="female">Female</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female"
                            @onchange="UpdateGender" checked="@IsFemaleRadioButtonChecked"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <label for="date-of-birth">Date of Birth</label>
                    <input type="date" id="date-of-birth" @bind="NewUser.DateOfBirth" />
                </div>
                <Button Text="Add User" OnClick="Save" />
            </form>
        </div>
        }
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    private async void Save()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        StateHasChanged();

        if (!AreFormValuesValid()) return;

        NewUser.Id = 0;
        NewUser.Password = NewUser.Name;
        NewUser.Role = roleService.Get("Participant");
        NewUser.Gender = Gender == "Male" ?
            Enumerations.Gender.Male : Enumerations.Gender.Female;

        if (await userService.AddOrUpdate(NewUser))
        {
            js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "User Added Successfully");

            NewUser = new User();
            Gender = "";
            StateHasChanged();
        } else
        {
            js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Couldn't Save User");
        }
    
        IsLoading = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

the loading text appears righ after the alert, but i want the loading text to appear right when i click the button. how do i change my code to achieve that.

i tried a lot of methods, and have been stuck for hours, can anyonw help? (this is a blazor server app project)

Comment: Try adding 'await Task.Delay(100)' after changing the variable 'IsLoading'.

Comment: @HH 100 ms is still miniscule. Let programmer put their number there. It's not a hard realtime system.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the UI can only happen during an `await`.
When the message only appears after the alert then `userService.AddOrUpdate()` isn't really async. Add a delay to update the screen:

```
  //private async void Save()   -- avoid `async void`
    private async Task Save()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
      //StateHasChanged();      -- you get this one for free
        await Task.Delay(1);

        if (!AreFormValuesValid()) return;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solution works.

You mentioned that userService.AddOrUpdate() isn;t really async, i am confused, shouldn't access to a database be async because it takes time? I know that making it a non async function works fine but i just think that making it async is better, what do you think about that?

Comment: Your code there is OK, but markng a method `async` doesn't mean it is (always) asynchronous. You have little control over that, and in Blazor you need to be sure sometimes. Hence the `Delay(1)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there are issues here around async. The save method should return a Task `private async Task Save()`. With that in place you get a complete stack trace only using the bottom example below. Its more verbose, but lets the stack trace point to this specific OnClick.

```
@*<Button Text="Add User" OnClick="Save" />  Provides incomplete stack trace*@
<Button Text="Add User" OnClick="(async () => await Save())" />
```

As far as having a long running synchronous task, the Yield method below is the direct way to transition into async operation. That can be used here, though it seems more likely that there is a design issue with the async method which takes so long running synchronously.

```cs
await Task.Yield();
```