# Blazor - how to disable button in child component and then enable it again when event call back method finish

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I had a form in child component similar like this (I currently using Radzen lib). We have a simple text box and a button. When the button click then it will trigger the method GetCacheMemoryUsages in parent component. I trigger it through event call back.

I would like to have the button in the child component disabled when it click , then it wait until the  method (GetCacheMemoryUsages) in parent component finished then enable it again. How could I do it ? Thank in advance

As you see I have tried to bind the disable property to bool variable _isFormDisabled however it does not work.

here is the Child Component code

```
    <RadzenTemplateForm TItem="SearchInputModel" Data=@_model Submit=@OnSubmit>
                <div class="col-sm-2 p-3">
                    <RadzenText TextStyle="TextStyle.Subtitle2" TagName="TagName.H3">Region Version</RadzenText>
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value=@_model.RegionVersion class="w-100" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 pt-5">
                    <RadzenButton Variant="Variant.Flat" Text="Search" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Dark" Disabled="@_isFormDisabled" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </RadzenTemplateForm>



@code
{
    bool _isFormDisabled;
    SearchInputModel _model = new ();

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<SearchInputModel> OnSearchClickEventCallback { get; set; }

    void OnSubmit(SearchInputModel model)
    {
        //THIS DOES NOT WORK
        _isFormDisabled = true;
        OnSearchClickEventCallback.InvokeAsync(model);
        _isFormDisabled = false;
    }
}
```

Here is Parent Component Code

```
<ChildComponent OnSearchClickEventCallback="@GetCacheMemoryUsages"></ChildComponent>
@code
{
    IEnumerable<CacheKeyMemoryUsage> _cacheKeyMemoryUsages = new List<CacheKeyMemoryUsage();

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<SearchInputModel> OnSearchClickEventCallback { get; set; }

   private void GetCacheMemoryUsages(SearchInputModel model)
    {
      // Doing something take long time here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
async Task OnSubmit(SearchInputModel model)
{
    _isFormDisabled = true;
    await Task.Delay(1);
    await OnSearchClickEventCallback.InvokeAsync(model);
    _isFormDisabled = false;
}
```

If you make it async and await you give the UI thread chance to update. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76379466/blazor-how-to-show-a-loading-text-immediately-after-clicking-a-button)

Here you have a working example: [here](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOmnYUkUTqYerpUw)

Comment: I think you have to await the InvokeAsync .

Comment: On re-read, you don't need the 2nd Delay(1), rendering will happen after the event anyway.

Comment: @HH I think that's right too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-7.0#an-asynchronous-handler-involves-multiple-asynchronous-phases

Comment: It made me thinking, as a matter of fact, if one awaits OnSearchClickEventCallback.InvokeAsync(model), there is no need for any await Task.Delay(1) in this case. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOwRagkLnOcdqGXs

Comment: That depends. You don't know 'how async' the subscribed handler method is. It could be totally synchronous or have a cpu-bound start section. The Delay(1) makes it certain.